# How to set focus correctly when deal with wm_nclbuttondown?

Tags: winapi, user-interface

I want to create a window that will dismiss when it lose its focus in the wm_nclbuttondown handler, just like what firefox's menu button window does. But I didn't manage to do it. The new window would lose its focus immediately after its creation.

So I digged with spy++ and found WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN would always cause main window focused, here is the messages logged with spy++:

[image]

in which 0xb13f2 is the main window's hwnd, and 0x46139a is the new window hwnd.

Then how to set focus correctly?

Comment: If you want to do something when you lose focus, use the WM_KILLFOCUS message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot methods:

1. pre-translate the wm_nclbuttdown to wm_lbuttondown.
2. nchittest all the window area as HTCLIENT and then try to handle
   the move and resize manually, but this modification is too huge to
   continue.
3. in wm_nclbuttondown handler, sendmessage wm_lbuttondown.
4. call setfocus a lot.

...

Some works, but bring other problems. Finally I used spy++ log the messages of firefox, and found that just make nchittest return HTCLIENT in the area where you need to handle left button down message.